# Single Page Application no WebView do Android Studio

Tags: angularjs, android-studio, webview, angular-routes, single-page-application

É possivel usar o Single page application do angular no WebView com o Android Studio?

Comment: o webview do Android Studio é algo tipo um mini browse, logicamente se voce tiver a referida pagina postada em um servidor que de suporte a essas funcionalidades, o WebView vai abrir a pagina com todas as suas requisições normalmente como se fosse o browser, (como se fosse, note bem).